# Persist java.util.Properties with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, properties, persistence

How would I go about persisting an object that has a `java.util.Properties` object in it?

Note that a `java.util.Properties` object has the ability to lookup properties not only in itself, but also in a *default* properties list. The default properties list is itself another `Properties` object, so it too can have another default properties list. Looking up a single property could traverse multiple `Properties` objects before the property is found.

The application I'm building needs override-able properties in a hierarchical manner like `Properties` provides, so I was thinking of using `Properties` instead of implementing my own data structure. But I'm confused on how I would persist them.

- Would I need to create a custom UserType? Any pointers on how to do this for this situation?
- Anyone know of a how-to or other resource that demonstrates how to persist Properties in Hibernate?

Answer (score 4):

not sure if it's a "piece of pie" thing, but since you can store the XML from a Properties instance and load an instance from an XML therefore you could have a @Lob property on your entity holding the XML that will be persisted. 
Something like:

```
 class MyEntity implements Serializable {
   @Transient
   Properties props;

   @Lob
   byte[] xmlProp; //the xml as a byte[]

   //ids, getters & setters ommited

 }
```

And then you can implement a DAO to do the hard work of persisting and retrieving your entity:

```
 class MyEntityDAO {

   public void persist(MyEntity entity){

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        entity.getProps().storeToXML(bos, "a simple comment if you like");

        byte[] byteStream = bos.toByteArray();
                entity.setXmlProp = byteStream;

                //save your instance with hibernate...

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

   public MyEntity retrieveById(Long id){

      Properties propFromDB = new Properties();

      MyEntity ent = //retrieve the instance with hibernate...

      try{
        Properties propFromDB = new Properties();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(ent.getXmlProp());
        propFromDB.load(bais);
        ent.setProp(propFromDB);
        return ent;
      } catch (IOException ioe){
       ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
   }
 }
```

Check methods storeToXML and loadFromXML at the [java.util.Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) API.

Hope this helps;

Comment: Very interesting Lucas.  The only problem I have with this method is that I won't be able to search based on the key/value pairs in the properties.  Do you know of any way around that?

Comment: Essentially you could switch the xmlProp from byte[] to String, fill in a String with the content of the ByteArray* and persist the xml itself on that property. That would give you the possibility to query the data, but it looks sort of hacky. What kind of query are your trying to run?

Answer (score 3):

The first questions is - do you need to store the hierarchy metadata, or you just want to store all properties. If it's the letter case, then simply add all the properties (using `getPropertyNames()`) to a `Map` end persist it (persisting maps is nearly trivial)

If you want to retain the hierarchy, then a question to ask is - how should this be represented in the database.

The simplest way I imagine is to have one table with the following columns:

```
id | key | value | properties_set_id | parent_properties_set_id
```

But how to do that - I can't think of immediately. Perhaps persist a `Set<PropertyEntry>`.

Comment: Bozho, I assume you'd make the Properties instance transient, but then at what point do you export the properties to a map?  I'm not sure of the mechanics of when to make it happen.

Comment: @Jason Nichols I meant it as a manual process. Or perhaps a `@PreX` event listener. Perhaps it is possible via a UserType, but I've never written such, so I can't tell.